# Miniconda not installing sqlite latest version within Python

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

I really hope my title makes sense I'm really new at this.

What I'm experiencing is the following: I installed miniconda and used the conda command to create an environment in which I installed django. Afterwards I created a django project running the command:

```
django-admin startproject {projectname}
```

afterwards I tried starting an app within the project running the following command:

```
python manage.py startapp {appname}
```

When I tried this I got an error that says:

```
File "C:\Users\fernando\Miniconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 63, in check_sqlite_version
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).
```

I've tried uninstalling miniconda and reinstalling it but the sqlite3 version doesn't seem to update since every time I reinstall miniconda and run the following commands:

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

I get 3.7.17 even when I uninstalled miniconda restart my computer and reinstalled it. Any Ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey so after a lot of trying I found out how to resolve my issue, turns out that when you install python using miniconda, Python uses the installed sqlite3 you have in your system which is here

`C:\Windows\System32\sqlite3.dll`

so I downloaded the most recent sqlite dll from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and replaced that sqlite3.dll on System32 folder once I did this I checked for the version of sqlite3 with python and got:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.28.0'
```

Success!